# How to Dispose BitmapDecoder object in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have developed a WPF Application, using `BitmapDecoder` to save images. While saving images i am getting an

> insufficient memory to complete the operation exception.

The code looks something like this:

```
BitmapDecoder imgDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(mem,
BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile, BitmapCacheOption.None);
```

I think BitmapDecoder object may be the cause of that exception; how do I dispose of the object?

Comment: FYI, you're supposed to 'accept' and/or upvote correct answers to your questions. That's how people say "thanks" on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue.  I have an app that loads thousands of images using the BitmapDecoder and was hitting memory problems.  I had to create a wrapper class ImageFileHandler that handled all interaction with the BitmapDecoder, then I stored my instance of BitmapDecoder in a WeakReference.  So if the OS needed the memory, my weak reference would give up the BitmapDecoder, and then every time my ImageFileHandler needed it, it would create a new one if necessary.

Comment: I think I am running into the same problem.  Could you please describe your solution a little more?

Answer (score 3):

Not only BmpBitmapDecoder, but all decoders (GifBitmapDecoder, PngBitmapDecoder, JpegBitmapDecoder, TiffBitmapDecoder) aren't disposable classes, so all you can do to dispose them is to say

```
_myDecoder = null; 
GC.Collect();
```

And let the garbage collector do its job.

If you prefer you can create a pool of `BitmapDecoder`s and load your images as `FileStream` which are disposables and contains the binary data of your images. Maybe the code below gives you an idea:

```
GC.Collect();
// Load the file stream if it hasn't been loaded yet
if (_imageDataStream == null)
    _imageDataStream = new FileStream(_imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
else
    _imageDataStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(_imagePath).ToUpper();
if (extension.Contains("GIF"))
    _decoder = new GifBitmapDecoder(_imageDataStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
        BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
else if (extension.Contains("PNG"))
    _decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(_imageDataStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
        BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
else if (extension.Contains("JPG") || extension.Contains("JPEG"))
    _decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(_imageDataStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
        BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
else if (extension.Contains("BMP"))
    _decoder = new BmpBitmapDecoder(_imageDataStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
        BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
else if (extension.Contains("TIF"))
    _decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(_imageDataStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
        BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
```

Comment: "let the garbage collector do its job" - so don't force the GC to collect. In most cases the GC knows what to do. Calling "GC.Collect()" and other gc functions can lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

BitmapDecoder is not disposable. Just make sure you don't keep any reference to the BitmapDecoder if you don't need it anymore, and the GC will do its job and collect the unused memory when needed.